# google datastore use order and filter together

Tags: node.js, sorting, date, datastore

I wanted to sort the records in google datastore based on dates and a condition.But when i try this in Nodejs code, i got error.

error in datastoreError: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: no matching index found. recommended index is:

- kind: mgr_api
  properties:

  - name: apiName
  - name: created

my code is

async function upsertVersions(namespaceOrKind, kind) {

```
const query = datastore.createQuery(namespaceOrKind, kind).order('created').filter('apiName', '=', 'retail');
return await datastore.runQuery(query);
```

}

Where the datatype of properties 'created' is a timestamp(date and time ) and 'apiName' is a string. When i use only filter i am able to get the results, But when i use both filter and order no results , i want to get results based on the created date and the apiName passed.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved now, i have created the indexes for the fields and after that it worked fine. Its that datastore will not support queries without indexes based on certain conditions and in my case it required indexes.